# What are the Current Custom Close Reasons of GIS SE?

Tags: support, faq, close-reasons

Each Stack Exchange site, through community consultation, using its per-site Meta is able to define at least three Custom Close Reasons.  GIS SE requested to have one more and that request was granted so it has four.

What are those four Custom Close Reasons?

Answer (score 3):

The Custom Close Reasons of GIS SE are currently set to:

1. When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it **in the question body**. Providing a **clear problem statement** and a code attempt helps others to help you.
2. This **problem cannot or can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the asker's circumstances may have rendered the question obsolete, or the question does not include a procedure to enable potential answerers to reproduce the same symptoms. Such questions are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers, but editing them to include more details can lead to re-opening.
3. Questions relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here but can be researched/asked at Stack Overflow (**software development**), Super User (**computing hardware and software**), Database Administrators (**relational databases**) and other SE sites
4. Questions that relate to the business of vendors and product teams, such as **licensing**, **pricing**, **release dates**, **submission of bug reports** and **enhancement requests**, etc, are off-topic here and should be directed instead to the official software support teams.

As can be seen at [Please automatically include text covering site specific close reasons in the help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186514/please-automatically-include-text-covering-site-specific-close-reasons-in-the-he) this GIS Meta answer is not automatically maintainable so if you see it become outdated please notify a moderator to edit it.  Our Custom Close Reasons are rarely changed, and when that is done, it is via GIS SE Meta Q&As like those which can be found using a search of https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22custom+close+reason%22+is%3Aquestion.