# Degree of severity to closing question options?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across a question titled [best choice for create relational between PostGIS and Mysql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/237898/73835) that I felt should be closed because it was both broad and could create a lot of opinion based answers ('a secondary question in the question asking which is better: PostGIS or MySQL').

Now I understand that it is better for questions to be flagged/closed than to be ignored. But when it comes to choosing which option, when several clearly fit, is there a scale of severity to work by? Or does it generally not matter as long as it is flagged/closed?

Comment: Try to choose the one in which feedback will help OP the most. If you think that the custom close reason messages are not enough, then leave a comment to OP providing more guidance about what to do. For example: _"This is a 'too broad' question, because you ask 3 very different questions, but if you end up sticking to question number 2 make sure it is more focused, because the way it is written it will collect opinion-based answers which is also not ok in this community, etc.."_

Comment: 3 questions in 1 should be 3 separate questions on GIS.SE for clarity to users. Hence on hold 'too broad'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever I see a question for which multiple close reasons seem applicable I think it is fine to choose any that you think resonates with that particular question.

I was advised early in my time here that closing as a duplicate (if it is) should perhaps take priority, and while I often make that choice, I think it is far from always applicable because, if a question is written poorly, then it can be a bit of a guess as to whether the duplicate really represents the same question.

Something about that particular question is that it contained [multiple questions](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/where-does-it-state-one-question-per-post-in-the-gis-stack-exchange-instructio), so really I needed to use the too broad close reason first, because until it is down to a single question it is not possible to characterize the improvement needed by the question as a whole i.e. one question in it might be seeking opinions, another might be unclear, and another might still be too broad (open-ended) in its own right.