# Getting answers for questions immediately

Tags: support, status-completed, questions

I post my question two days back and i have not yet received the required answer for that. Now what can i do to get the answer for my question soon? And also i don't know whether my question has been closed or still in open status.

below are the link i posted two days ago
[How to set NULL as default value for a date field in QGIS 2.4?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104466/how-to-set-null-as-default-value-for-a-date-field-in-qgis-2-4)

Answer (score 9):

The best way to obtain quick and comprehensive answers here is by making your question as clear and easy to understand as you can.  You have an edit button beneath it which you can use to keep improving your question as potential answerers ask you for clarifications via comments.  Be aware that comments do not form part of your question so if you say anything in them which is important then it is best to include them as part of your next question revision.

From a recent Q&A here ([Should Statements of Urgency be removed from Questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions)) it is evident that the community here is anxious to answer questions quickly but as volunteers considers any statements of urgency for faster attention as being inappropriate.

Your question has not been closed and does not currently have any close votes against it.  However, something I notice is that you appear to have provided some extra information as an answer which may be confusing potential answerers into thinking that you are providing a solution.  All new information about your question should go into the body of your original question.  Self-answering is allowed but reserve that for when you have a solution to post.