# Asking questions about obtaining free geospatial data?

Tags: support, status-completed, scope, questions, data

I have asked [a question about downloading free geospatial data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6778/free-quad-polarization-sar-images-of-san-francisco-in-bands-x-and-l) on the [Open Data (beta) Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) but because of the temporarily low traffic of this beta site, this question has reached to only 9 views in two days and no one has answered it already.

I have two other questions too that I know they probably won't get an answer on this site soon and I'm in urgent need.

Can I ask these three questions about free geospatial questions here just because that I need a quick answer?

Answer (score 3):

I am glad that you have considered the [Open Data (beta) Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) for your (open?) data question first.

I think any urgency in your need is a separate issue that has been the subject of Q&A here previously in [Should Statements of Urgency be removed from Questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions) so I am going to focus on whether your proposed questions would appear to be on-topic here.

Our community's attitude to that has been the subject of Q&A here previously too in [Are questions about obtaining geospatial data on topic?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-geospatial-data-on-topic) and it seems to me that questions tagged [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) are not always welcomed but they can be considered on-topic.

When asking [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) questions on Main I would recommend that you pay particular attention to describing what you have already done to try and answer your own question prior to posting here.  In the case of cross-posting https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6778/free-quad-polarization-sar-images-of-san-francisco-in-bands-x-and-l I think you should start with a link to that, and also add a comment to your question there to say that you have now also asked here, and why.