# Asking for clarifications with less than 50 reputation points?

Tags: support, faq, comments, reputation

I'm a beginner at GIS and I've finally found [Setting fill style in polygon in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125226) which I think I can answer.

However, the person posting the question has not given enough details for me to be able to give a good answer.

How do you ask for more details if you have less than 50 points (with less than 50 points one can't comment on someone else's posts)?

Can I ask for more details as an answer?

Answer (score 10):

Please do not ask for more details as an answer because that area is reserved for direct answers to the question.

The 50 point reputation requirement is there for the reasons discussed in [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) so I recommend reading that Q&A and following the advice in its only, and highly upvoted, answer.

I think the best way to get to 50 points quickly is to ask a few good questions and I recommend the collective advice on how to do that here which is documented in [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) at GIS SE.

If you prefer to try and get there via answers rather than questions then in the particular instance you cite, if there is not enough information to be certain of whether you are answering the question they are trying to ask, but you think you know, then just state some assumptions you are making and provide the answer.  However, I would recommend not going too far out on a limb when you do this.

As noted in [@AndreSilva's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4877/115) you can get to 50 more incrementally by suggesting edits to posts (try to make them substantial) because if they are approved each gets you two points.

From @whuber:

> ... another way to acquire the privilege of commenting. From [our help
>   pages,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) "If you
>   are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more
>   reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100
>   reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This
>   will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where
>   you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time
>   you log in."

Answer (score 3):

Besides what [PolyGeo has already said](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/asking-for-clarifications-with-less-than-50-reputation-points/3861#3861) my advice to gain initial 50 points of reputation is to help curating the site by suggesting improvements on questions and answers through **editing**. Each edit suggestion that gets approved is worth +2 points (then, you need 25 successful suggestions which is not too much).

One advantage of such approach is that it helps to get acquainted with the site, as you read posts and learn how to ask and answer.

This is also useful when one doesn't want to ask questions just for the sake of asking to gain points (the same for answers).

See the following posts which will guide you about how to edit posts (and help understanding how editing works in Stack Exchange):

- [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)