# Reputation limiting actions is a problem

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

I understand why reputation limits user actions, as it makes moderation easier, however it's very frustrating.  I've got a few fairly niche GIS questions, and i'd love to be able to comment on older questions to speak to people who have had similar problems in the past (since messaging people directly isn't a thing here), but I require a certain amount of reputation to do so.  Unfortunately, because I'm new to GIS, it's not as if I can answer any questions competently enough to gain that reputation.

Also, maybe this is better suited to a separate thread, but is there a way to purchase reputation to use for bounties?

Comment: your rep is on 53 points you can comment.

Comment: since messaging people directly isn't a thing here? that is what https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gis.stackexchange.com is for you can create a new room for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Tips for how to quickly acquire the 50 points of reputation necessary for the [comment everywhere privilege](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) can be found at [Asking for clarifications with less than 50 reputation points?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3860)

However, when you say that you would:

> love to be able to comment on older questions to speak to people who
>   have had similar problems in the past (since messaging people directly
>   isn't a thing here)

I worry that you are wanting to use comments for functions that are more akin to those of a discussion forum than a focused Q&A site like GIS SE.

From the the [comment everywhere privilege](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) page you will see that

> Comments are not recommended for ... **Secondary discussion** or
>   debating a controversial point; please use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead

It sounds like you are wanting to use comments to undertake secondary discussion about a post's content instead of using them to seek clarifications that help a question receive an answer, or help answers to a specific question to be easier to understand by future visitors to it.

The idea of purchasing bounty has been rejected many times in Meta SE Q&As like [How to Buy Rep Only for Use as a Bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69537/215590)

For a quick introduction to how this site is designed to work I strongly recommend taking its 2-minute [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).