# Is there any point approving minor edits to very old questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

For example, this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/154910

It's just a minor edit "for grammer" to a question that is over 4 years old. I know this has been raised before, but it feels like an edit just to gain reputation/badges. And won't it bring the question to the top of the pile when nothing really has changed?

So I guess my question is, would it be wrong to reject minor grammar edits on very old questions? I don't see any benefit to accepting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Changing

> How do I re-run the model

to

> How can I do a re-run to the model

is not an improvement at all. This suggested edit should be rejected.

However, I would not generalize this to "grammar edits on very old questions". Many posts that were *written* a long time ago are being *read* today by people coming from search engines. If poor writing makes those posts hard to read, it should be corrected.

Answer (score 8):

New users are encouraged to make edits to gain reputation to unlock privileges such as commenting. Sources:

- [How does a lurker gain reputation to receive privilege for commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting)
- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)
- [Asking for clarifications with less than 50 reputation points?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/asking-for-clarifications-with-less-than-50-reputation-points)

To be consistent with the accepted answers to those questions, we should allow minor edits that only correct spelling or grammatical errors.

Based on the comments on those question pages, it seems that many new users are frustrated at their inability to participate by commenting. I think that any new user who makes the effort to build up their reputation on this site should be encouraged. Of course with the disclaimer that truly unhelpful edits should be discarded.

After all, the Suggested Edit Review Queue on GIS SE is not exactly overflowing with minor edits.

[image]

(sound of crickets)

**TL;DR: If an edit makes a positive change, even a minor one, go ahead and approve it.**

Answer (score 0):

Many edits of old questions and answers reflect the newer technology. For instance the person asks in 2014 a question on how to resolve the issue using VBA for software X version 2.0, then someone in 2023 would edit the code in VBA replacing it with python saying that this is how it is done for version 10 of software X. In my opinion these edits need to be rejected as they do not reflect the technology or the methodology during that time.
I would lock these questions if an answer has been accepted if the question has been asked beyond a certain number of years unless if the OP re-opens it which I doubt.
This is my opinion after reviewing a few edits.
but as *@csk said: If an edit makes a positive change, even a minor one, go ahead and approve it.*

Comment: The edits you describe as replacing code are far from minor and should only be done and approved with extreme care. Nevertheless evolving timeless Q&As covering multiple software versions is important and discussed at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4420/115