# Is "pure" remote sensing question on topic for GIS SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

My question is a  "pure" remote sensing question. Having been corrected by @PolyGeo before(as shown here - [How do you classify unclassified pixels in a land cover geotiff tile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149280/how-do-you-classify-unclassified-pixels-in-a-land-cover-geotiff-tile)) I thought I will ask here before I post on GIS SE.

I have to do something similar to this paper - http://www.bsc.es/media/412.pdf

I have land cover data classified at a resolution of 30 meters derived from Landsat images.

I need to calculate parameters such as albedo, surface emissivity, surface roughness, etc for a small region and  a climatological period(say Boreal summer). When I use the Semi Automatic Classifier Plugin to download Landsat images I only get a small number of images over my area for the period June through August (I checked for last year). In order to do a climatological analysis I need at least 100 images (preferably a morning pass and a afternoon pass) over period of  a Boreal summer.

Would it be OK to use MODIS images and then do a downscaling to obtain these parameters or MODIS and then downscale to get an approximate value for the albedo and other parameters ? Does MODIS give more images than Landsat ? Are there other satellites that provide free images ?

Is my question(s) on topic ? Obviously I can split this up into several questions as the mods may suggest.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question here to include links to the two questions that you feel I have corrected you on, please?  The question you describe here certainly seems to be on topic, even if as written it seems too broad for focussed Q&A.

Comment: @PolyGeo - one I have deleted. The second one sure.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I am attempting to make a very focussed question. For starters I can tackle albedo alone. I am still left with two questions. One is can MODIS provide the same information after downscaling ? Second can MODIS provide more passes than Landsat ?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you are asking two questions in your proposed question but our [Tour] says up front that we are looking for one question per question.

Comment: @PolyGeo - got it. I will make it one question per question. I presume the question(s) that got left out can be asked as a separate question ?

Comment: As the [Tour] says: 

"Your most important question is important to us

Asking one, and only one, important question within your Question helps attract prompt and clear Answers.

Your other questions are just as easy to research/ask separately!"

Answer (score 4):

I can only think that by "corrected" you are referring to the below deleted comment of mine:

> This is not a question that I would attempt to answer because it falls
>   outside of my skillset. However, I think what you are asking goes out
>   of focus by the inclusion of more than one question mark - you have
>   six! Also, your title tells potential answerers little about what you
>   are asking. I recommend reviewing this Meta GIS SE answer for some
>   ideas on structuring your question: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353
>   –  PolyGeo♦ Jun 1 at 22:07

after which you applied an edit to your question and I commented:

> I like the latest revision of your question much more. –  PolyGeo♦ Jun
>   2 at 1:26

My deleted comment on your deleted question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132841/gis-design-patterns, which is the other correction referred to was:

> My immediate impression is that this is too broad because you are
>   asking for a list of references and providing the first two on that
>   list (which are link only, and thus far less useful than when
>   summarised here). You use a term "Gang Of Four" which I think you
>   should provide a description of (and/or link to). –  PolyGeo♦ Feb 3 at
>   6:53

In any event, the question you describe here certainly seems to be on topic, even if as written it seems too broad for focussed Q&A.

Please do not use GIS SE Meta to pre-post your questions for community approval because GIS SE Main is by far the better place to have the community give their opinion on them.

Comment: @PolyGeo- Not four questions but two. One was on GIS design patterns which I deleted.

Comment: I have no problems with you correcting me :-)

Comment: Please do not misunderstand me.

Comment: It's no problem but twice today people have tried to have questions pre-OK-ed here in Meta before posting them on Main - we cannot afford to be double-handling each of the 59 questions per day that we currently get on Main.

Comment: I understand but as a responsible user we do not want our questions to be voted down or get a tumble weed badge. We also want to contribute to the community. Once you are corrected you feel hesitant to ask before getting prior approval.