# Clarifying future of Geomatics and Remote Sensing proposal in Area 51?

Tags: discussion

Regarding my two previous discussions in this site:

- [Should GIS.SE be widened to be Geomatics.se?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/should-gis-se-be-widened-to-be-geomatics-se)
- [Are people in this community interested in having a new site for other Geospatial technologies?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/are-people-in-this-community-interested-in-having-a-new-site-for-other-geospatia)

it seems that no one agrees with changing the name of the site

Also seems that it's not the time to propose a new site for remote sensing because of lack of audience at the time being
As the last discussion do you agree with this suggestion?

We don't change the name of GIS.SE
We don't propose a new site
We add some tags to the current site that cover remote sensing, photogrammetry, geodesy
We change keywords in the tour page to broaden the audience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- I agree with NOT changing the name of GIS SE
- I am NOT against a new site for Remote Sensing but any impetus for that should come from Remote Sensing practitioners within and outside of GIS SE
- I think new tags should emerge organically. For example, are there any remote sensing, photogrammetry or geodesy tags missing that you think would be applied to a few hundred questions over the next few years?  As my rule of thumb I usually only coin new tags when that is the case, and once the first few to ten or so questions have already been asked.  I would not be in favour of creating a lot of new tags that are rarely used.
- I think the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [On Topic page of our Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) could be tweaked along the lines of the [answer by @AndreSilva to an earlier question today](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4022).  I am not sure that this actually broadens our audience but it may give some reassurance to "sub communities" such as remote sensing, photogrammetry or geodesy that we are very happy to have them with us up until such time that they may feel they want to "go it alone".  I am not certain, but I do not think we have ever seen a question here closed as off-topic for being about remote sensing, photogrammetry or geodesy.  When any remote sensing, photogrammetry, geodesy *or GIS* questions are closed it is usually about their scope and/or clarity.

I'm going to edit the title of your question so that it acts as a summary of its content.