# Improving opening paragraphs of GIS SE Help Center (and Tour)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, help-center

Our opening [Help page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) starts with these two paragraphs (some common to its [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)) :

> **Geographic Information Systems** is a question and answer site for people interested in **GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy
>   and Surveying,** *as well as Programming/Databases specific to the
>   aforementioned*. It is built and run by you as part of the Stack
>   Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we are working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to every question about
>   **GIS**. Our [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) provides further guidance to help in posting good questions and answers.
>
> Although the scope of questions appropriate here is wide, befitting
>   the range of GIS applications, **please make an initial effort
>   to research the answer before you ask a question**.  That will
>   help you write a great, focused question that gets excellent answers. 
>   Questions that are too basic (meaning the answer is indexed in any
>   number of general internet reference sources designed specifically to
>   find that type of information) will be closed.

This is a page that moderators of the site can edit, and its current wording stems from [How should we describe GIS Stack Exchange on its Tour page?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4028/115)

I think the two paragraphs currently serve our community well.

However, with the addition of one word I think it would serve our community even better.

Rather than suggest that word at the outset, I would like to ask whether anyone has any suggestions for slight re-wording of these two paragraphs that they would like to see?

Don't forget that these are only the first two of seven paragraphs on that help page so any suggestions should also stay in context with the remainder.

Comment: We would need to ensure that the [tour] page is also updated as the first few lines on that page are taken from the first paragraph on our help page.

Comment: I've implemented the top two answers (https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4601/115 and https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4602/115) which appear to have clear consensus with votes of 9/0 and 8/0 respectively.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to drop the last sentence:

> Questions that are too basic (meaning the answer is indexed in any
>   number of general internet reference sources designed specifically to
>   find that type of information) will be closed.

I like to consider GIS SE as the ultimate repository for questions all along the spectrum from basic to advanced. Why would we not want GIS SE to be the "internet reference source" for all questions related to GIS? Additionally, I would consider "Too basic" as subjective and difficult to enforce.

Comment: I think that you are absolutely right. Its not the change I was thinking of but that sentence really just says the same as the bolded bit before it and in a less welcoming way.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion herein is not what I was originally thinking, but in this sentence:

> That will help you write a great, focused question that gets excellent
>   answers.

the word "gets" could be replaced by "attracts" to remind, with subtlety,  that askers are seeking volunteered efforts to answer their questions.

This would make that sentence:

> That will help you write a great, focused question that attracts
>   excellent answers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest removing the italic formatting in:

> *as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned.*

It is a bit disrupting. The lack of bold formatting in this part already says Programming/Databases have something different from previous subjects.

<sub>As alternative, I'd also support to bold formatting the entire sentence (or just bolding 'Programming and Databases').</sub>

Comment: I agree.  What about removing the italics from that bit but moving just **Programming/Databases** into bold?  That way its not too much bold but emphasizes that Programming and Databases are just as important to us as GUI.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I did not understand the last part of your comment (perhaps 'as GIS'?), but agree with your suggestion.

Comment: For new users often all they see is the OOTB GUI and simple data.  It may only be quite a bit later that they start to understand that the GUI is customizable by programming and that data types come in many different types and storage formats.  So my comment is intended to attract those interested in spatial libraries, spatial data and not just spatial OOTB GUIs.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this answer to try to draw all the suggestions into a single post.  If it floats to the top we can be confident that it has community support in its entirety.  If not, then depending on where it sits, we can try to assess what bits of it have consensus.

> **Geographic Information Systems** is a question and answer site for people interested in **GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy
>   and Surveying,** as well as **Programming** and **Databases** specific to the
>   aforementioned. It is built and run by you as part of the Stack
>   Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we are working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to focused questions about
>   **GIS**. Our [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) provides further guidance to help in posting good questions and answers.
>
> Although the scope of questions appropriate here is wide, befitting
>   the range of GIS applications, **please make an initial effort
>   to research the answer before you ask a question**.  That will
>   help you write a great, focused question that attracts excellent answers.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence below has concerned me for a while:

> With your help, we are working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to every question about
>   **GIS**.

I think it implies that we are an "ask anything, any way you like" site.  However, we have a number of guidelines throughout our Help and this Meta site, and a number of close reasons, that says to me that we do not seek  to answer *every* conceivable question about GIS.

I think the simple insertion of the word *focused* in that sentence will bring us much closer to describing the type of GIS questions we seek.

I also like the [suggestion of @Midavalo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/improving-opening-paragraphs-of-gis-se-help-center-and-tour?cb=1#comment8409_4605) to drop the word "every".

I propose this sentence as a replacement:

> With your help, we are working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to  focused questions about
>   **GIS**.

Comment: +1.  I don't like the word "every", but a slight modification to your verysion  - *With your help, we are working together to build a library of detailed answers to focused questions about GIS*

Comment: @Midavalo I think your suggestion improves it even more so I'm sure you won't mind me incorporating it.

Comment: Of course, no problem