# scope of "opinion-based"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

If a question is asking explicitly about "principles, statements or characteristics" stated by communities of GIS users, along with "pointers to some expert, authoritative or in depth discussion or reflection" on the subject, can it be put on hold as "opinion-based"?

reference:

[why there is even a POSTgis day](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261941/why-there-is-even-a-postgis-day)

Comment: I'm not sure that's the sole or even the right reason for closing your question.  Nevertheless, https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask provides criteria that indicate it's not a suitable question for the site.

Comment: can be discussed in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis

Comment: @Mapperz: useful comment, thx

Answer (score 2):

The guidance when voting to place on hold as **primarily opinion-based** is:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

Your question [why there is even a POSTgis day](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261941/why-there-is-even-a-postgis-day) was titled:

> **why there is even a POSTgis day**

and asked:

> Which ones are exactly Gis Day's principles, statements or
>   characteristics that POSTgis Day people disagrees with? To what degree
>   are both events celebrating exactly the same, and to what degree are
>   they different in a such a manner that they are separate events?
>
> Kindly provide pointers to some expert, authoritative or in depth
>   discussion or reflection on wich your answer is based

I did not vote on your question but, if I had seen it then I would probably have voted to place in on hold as either:

- too broad because it asks more than one question; or
- primarily opinion-based

I think the latter (the subject of your question here) would be perfectly valid because you ask potential answerers to specify what they disagree with and indicate that you seek a discussion.

GIS SE is [not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/215590); it is intended for focused Q&A.  Any time a question strays too far from describing what you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck I think you run the risk of it being poorly received and likely to attract down and/or close votes.

Your profile indicates that you are relatively new to the site so if you have not already seen it, I would recommend reviewing [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange) which is linked to from our [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) via our [Help Center](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help).