# Is this question against the rules of this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

My question ([Finding the distance between two points at sea - avoiding land](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445132)) was closed, and in a comment I got the following reasoning:

> *GIS SE is a problem-solving site. So far, all you have is a task. If you choose an approach and make an attempt to address the task, and
> encounter a problem and document that problem, the you'll have a
> Question to be answered. Right now you have more of a discussion
> topic, but GIS SE isn't a discussion forum.*

However, as the user's second most upvoted post was an answer to "why is arcgis called arcgis?" - which isn't a problem to be solved. This leads me to suspect that this person is closing my question not because it is breaking the rules, but for some other reason.

Later the question was opened and then closed as being a duplicate (that is a separate discussion). I do not understand if that means the initial closing was invalid.

If my question is breaking the rules, how can I format it to follow them?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about two questions from Main, with the second being a re-phrasing of the first:

- [Finding the distance between two points at sea - avoiding land](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445132/finding-the-distance-between-two-points-at-sea-avoiding-land;) and
- [Seeking algorithm for finding shortest path around obstacles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445229/implementation-of-an-algorithm-for-finding-the-shortest-path-around-obstacles)

The first question was closed for lacking a code attempt where your unmarked question seemed to be seeking a solution from one or more of "PostGIS, SQLite (SQL) and Python (which means also GeoPandas)".  For questions seeking code (SQL or Python), we usually ask for a code attempt to be the starting point.  If you were not seeking code, but just an algorithm instead, then you could have removed all references to software and asked just about an algorithm.

The second question got closer to doing that, but it still mentioned "Python or Postgis" so to me it still seemed to be looking for a solution/implementation rather than help finding an algorithm. In any event, I think it should have been a major edit to your first question rather than being asked as a new one.  Since, it was asked, another moderator voted to close it as a duplicate of an earlier question ([Creating optimised path between nodes avoiding polygons entities using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190640/create-an-optimised-path-between-nodes-avoiding-polygons-entities)) and that seemed like a reasonable action to me.

To navigate your way through our focused Q&A format, which is very different to a discussion forum, I offer these two thoughts on how it works:

- There are very few rules that must be followed.  Instead, there are many guidelines that the community reinforces or disperses via their voting; and
- There is an FAQ on [Asking good questions for GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange) in which the advice to keep software and algorithm questions separate is reinforced.